# SQL: select users that are in both test variant A en B

Tags: sql, mysql

hope you can help write a sql query for table X.

I have a table with rows per timestamp, filled with User_ID's and weather they have been in variant A or B of the a/b test.

I want to select all the User_ID's that where In both A and B. In this table example that would only give me
User_ID 4.

Next I would like to drop the rows of these User_ID's where A=1, so I only have B=1 left.

Who know how to write this?

| timestamp | User_ID | In_variant_A | In_variant_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-10-2023 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 11-10-2023 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 12-10-2023 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 13-10-2023 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 14-10-2023 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 15-10-2023 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 16-10-2023 | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| 17-10-2023 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 18-10-2023 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 19-10-2023 | 8 | 1 | 0 |

I tried using an where statement for where A=1 and B=1, nut that just gives me 0  records

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be using a subquery with the matching id and delete only the records where In_variant_B <> 1 for the matching ids.

To identify all the User_ID's that where In both A and B

```
select User_ID 
from yourtable y
group by User_ID 
having max(In_variant_A) = 1 and max(In_variant_B) = 1;
```

Delete query

```
delete y.* 
from yourtable y
inner join (select User_ID 
            from yourtable y
            group by User_ID 
            having max(In_variant_A) = 1 and max(In_variant_B) = 1 
            ) id_to_del on id_to_del.User_ID=y.User_ID
where In_variant_B <> 1;
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/lV8OM_YJ)